# Regex , split string into array vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have an address as string and i want to show it in 2 lines , for example address

```
 A Building 10 mynew Road Singapore 208718
```

I want to show as follows ,

```
A Building 10 mynew Road
Singapore 208718
```

I have done it in a following way ,

```
Dim parts1 As String() = Regex.Split(addr, "singapore", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
 If (parts.Length > 1) Then
    addr = parts(0) + "<br/> Singapore" + parts(1)
 End If
```

But the problem i have is , the text `Singapore` may come as `S'pore` as well , in this time how I can split with regular expression ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex with an alternation:

```
"[Ss](?:inga|')pore"
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `[Ss]` matches letter `s` or `S`
- `(?:inga|')`: matches text `inga` or `'`
- `pore`: Matches text `pore`

Comment: I'm just curious to know what does `?:inga` means , is it a global search ?

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capture group. [See details](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#:~:text=Non%2DCapturing%20Groups&text=The%20question%20mark%20and%20the,the%20end%20of%20the%20regex.&text=This%20regex%20has%20no%20quantifiers.)